# Linear indepedent holomorphic functions

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, functional-analysis

Suppose you have a given set of holomorphic functions $e_\alpha(z)=\exp(\alpha_1z_1+\dots+\alpha_nz_n)$ for different $\alpha=(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)$ in an open set of $\mathbb{C}^n$. How can I decide whether or not they are linearly independent over $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: try a linear combination? try to show that you can make any holomorphic function with these linear combinations?

Comment: In general I would agree, but so far I cant show anything by that approach

Comment: are the $\alpha$'s real?

Comment: They are from an open subset of $\mathbb{C}^n$! Sry my OP didnt specify $\alpha$

Comment: I'm thinking wrong, try to do the integral of $e_\alpha \overline{e_\beta}$, for distinct $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and hopefully you will get zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes they are independent.

It can be shown inductively.

For $N=1$. Obvious. Assume that it is true for $N=k$, i.e., whenever
$$
c_1\exp(a^1\cdot z)+\cdots+c_k\exp(a^k\cdot z)=0,
$$
then $c_1=\cdots=c_k=0$. [Here $a^j=(a^j_1,\ldots,a^j_n)$.] Now let
$$
c_1\exp(a^1\cdot z)+\cdots+c_k\exp(a^k\cdot z)+c_{k+1}\exp(a^{k+1}\cdot z)=0.
$$
This implies that
$$
c_1\exp\big( (a^1-a^{k+1})\cdot z\big)+\cdots+c_k\exp\big( (a^k-a^{k+1})\cdot z\big)+c_{k+1}=0,
$$
and differentiating with respect to $z_j$ we obtain
$$
c_1(a^1_j-a^{k+1}_j)\exp\big( (a^1-a^{k+1})\cdot z\big)+\cdots+c_k(a^k_j-a^{k+1}_j)\exp\big( (a^k-a^{k+1})\cdot z\big)=0.
$$
Now we can use the inductive hypothesis and obtain
$$
c_1(a^1_j-a^{k+1}_j)=\cdots=c_k(a^k_j-a^{k+1}_j)=0,
$$
and as the above is true for every $j=1,\ldots,n$, we finally obtain that
$$
c_1=\cdots=c_k=0$,
$$
and consequently also $c_{k+1}=0$.

Comment: Nice answer. Thanks alot!